# Confused about the use of break in this nested loop

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 for(int r = 0; r<3; r++)
    {
       for(int c = 0; c<=r; c++)
       {
         if(c == 1)
           break;
         cout<<'*';
       }
     cout<<endl;
     }

 return 0;
}
```

This code outputs:

```
*
*
*
```

My question is why is does it not output:

```
*

*
```

My logic is that the first loop runs with r = 0. Then calling the inner loop where c = 0. The first if statement is not true and so * is printed. This loop ends resulting in c = 1 as well as the larger loop where r now = 1. The main loop begins again sufficing all conditions but for some reason still prints a * from the inner loop even the the if command instructs a break to be called.

My possible thoughts are that:
1. There are no brackets around the if statement?
2. break; for some reason doesn't break the loop and instead the if statement(idk why this would be the case)
3. Magic?

Any help is appreciated as if its not already clear I am still very novice to the C++ language.

Comment: On the each iteration of the outer loop `c` gets initialized again to `0` (because the *entire* inner loop starts again)

Comment: Stepping through the code with the debugger will show you how it is working.  Also just walking through the logic on paper will show you why it always prints.

Answer (score 1):

`break` only breaks out of the innermost loop, not all loops. So the output is generated like so:

```
* // r = 0, c = 0
* // r = 1, c = 0
* // r = 2, c = 0
```

Comment: But why did not it execute `cout<<endl;`?

Comment: It did, that's why the `*` are on separate lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you restructure the logic, you will find that your *inner loop* is equivalent to :

```
for(int c = 0; c < 1 ; c++)
       {
         cout<<'*';
       }
```

Now, the outer loop will iterate 3 times R->{0,1,2) .. and for all R's, your *inner* loop gets chance to iterate and only 1 iteration .. Thus you get three * prints.

Answer (score 0):

`break` literally breaks out of the innermost `for` loop.

It exits the loop it's in and the code continues as if the loop was finished.

Answer (score 0):

The `break` instruction will interrupt the current `for` loop on that line. Thus, the programm will continue the execution from the next instruction after that block, which is `cout<<endl;`.

If no `cout<<endl;` were executed, your output would have looked like this:

```
***
```

---

To get a blank line, you need to add another `cout<<endl;` before the `break` instruction, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    for(int r = 0; r<3; r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c<=r; c++) {
            if(c == 1) {
                cout<<endl;
                break;
            }
            cout<<'*';
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

This code will print this:

```
* // r = 0, c = 0
  // new line
* // r = 1, c = 0
  // new line
* // r = 2, c = 0
  // new line
```